# The least possible value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the least possible value for :$$(x-1)^2+(x-2)^2+(x-3)^2+(x-4)^2+(x-5)^2$$

For every real $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x-1)^2+(x-2)^2+(x-3)^2+(x-4)^2+(x-5)^2$

$=(y+2)^2+(y+1)^2+y^2+(y-1)^2+(y-2)^2$.Let $(y=(x-3))$

$=5y^2+2(1^2+2^2)\ge2(1^2+2^2)$

Equality occurs at $y=0\Rightarrow x=3$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any calculus knowledge, you can use techniques learned in algebra/pre-calculus.

You can square each term in $(x-1)^2+(x-2)^2+(x-3)^2+(x-4)^2+(x-5)^2$ and collect like terms to get the form $ax^2 + bx + c$.

Since $a$ will be positive, we know this is a parabola opening up, like:

[image]

The highest or lowest point on a parabola is the vertex. Since this parabola opens upward, we know that we will have a minimum at the vertex.

To find $x$, use $\displaystyle x = -\frac{b}{2a}$. This is the $x$ that gives the minimum value. Plug this back into your $ax^2 + bx + c$ expression to find the minimum value.

Comment: squares do not work this way.

Comment: @JoshB. Oops! Revised my answer.

Comment: much better, and gives an intuitive graphical understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A twice differentiable function $f(x)$ is minimised iff $f'(x) = 0$ and $f''(x)>0$

Alternative hint: Expand out the brackets and write the expression in the form $ax^2+bx+c$ and then complete the square.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$(x-1)^2+(x-2)^2+(x-3)^2+(x-4)^2+(x-5)^2 \ge 0$

$5x^2+1+4+9+16+25 \ge 15x$

$5x^2 +55 -15x \ge 0 \implies x^2+11-3x \ge 0$

Aliter: $(x-3)=k$

You get

$(k+2)^2+(k+1)^2+(k)^2+(k-1)^2+(k-2)^2 \ge 0$

$k^2+11 \ge 0$